# End of script output before headers Apache 2.4 Error

Tags: c, apache

We have just upgraded to Apache 2.4 from 2.2 and our fastcgi apps are now causing the error message 'End of script output before headers'.

All the apps and libraries, which are all in C, have been recompiled using the latest libraries from fastcgi.com and they worked fine before the upgrade.

Any clues as to the cause of the problem would be appreciated.

The server is Fedora 19

As it turned out the problem was with a shared object file that wasn't of the correct version. For some odd reason that error did not show in the log.

So, question should be closed.

Comment: What is OS of your server? Have you tried [this idea](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4900)?

Comment: @llay, Sadly that did not help.

Comment: You might like to add an answer to your own question, and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out the problem was with a shared object file that wasn't of the correct version. For some odd reason that error did not show in the log.