# Apache CGI in user directory "End of script output before headers"

Tags: linux, apache, cgi

I know there are some questions about this topic, but none seems to solve my issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608627/end-of-script-output-before-headers-hello-pl) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644384/django-end-of-script-output-before-headers) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039942/end-of-script-output-before-headers-apache-2-4-error).

I'm on Linux, Fedora21, and I'm trying to enable per user directory CGI script. I followed [these](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html#cgi) instructions, but without success.

I get the error:

```
[cgi:error] End of script output before headers: test.cgi
```

`test.cgi` is an executable sh file, containing a very simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
echo "Hello"
```

which has executable flag and runs without problems from shell.
I also tried with Python: same result.

I also disabled selinux for good measure.

I also tried setting the `debug` level to Apache's ErrorLog, but all I get is only "granted" permissions before the error above.

I also configured the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf` file with

```
<Directory "/home/*/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/*/public_html/cgi-bin/>
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
    SetHandler cgi-script
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .exe .pl .py .vbs
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and restarted the server. No success. Everything looks fine to me, I can't understand... What's wrong??

## EDIT:

I forgot to add that the issue is just for per-user directory: if I move the same script to `/var/www/cgi-bin` directory, it works as expected.

## EDIT 2:

The shell does exist:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/sh
```

Comment: try `echo` without the double quotes

Comment: Tried, sadly it's not that :(

Comment: What command did you use to run it from the shell?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls /usr/bin/sh` ?

Comment: To run from the shell I used `bash test.cgi`, `sh test.cgi` and `./test.cgi`. They all give the same output. The file is naturally executable. The `sh` shell exists (see the updated question)

Comment: Usually CGI scripts have an `alias ...` command in Apache settings. It could have been that it was set and forced the search for CGIs in that directory only.

Comment: @AlexisWilke sorry for the late answer: yes, I did have an `alias` command in the `httpd.conf`, but even without it the issue remains.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I solved that. Thanks to @JimB, because in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265735/apache-cgi-in-user-directory-end-of-script-output-before-headers#comment46809331_29178112) they pointed out SUEXEC, which I didn't know about (or simply ignored till now).

After reading a bit the [suEXEC documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/suexec.html), I understood the the problem had to be there. So, I took a look at the configuration:

```
# suexec -V
 -D AP_DOC_ROOT="/var/www"
 -D AP_GID_MIN=1000
 -D AP_HTTPD_USER="apache"
 -D AP_LOG_SYSLOG
 -D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
 -D AP_UID_MIN=1000
 -D AP_USERDIR_SUFFIX="public_html"
```

and everything looked Ok (good uid/gid for my user, userdir_suffix is fine, etc). So I took a look at the system logs:

```
# journalctl -b | grep "suexec"
May 22 11:43:12 caladan suexec[5397]: uid: (1000/user) gid: (1000/user) cmd: test.cgi
May 22 11:43:12 caladan suexec[5397]: directory is writable by others: (/home/user/public_html/cgi-bin)
```

and *that's* the problem: my **`cgi-bin` directory was writable by others**.

I fixed by simply changing the permissions to `755`.

Comment: Would have been interesting to know : 1/ the URL you've been calling 2/ If you used suexec or not. I actually don't like the security hole of being able to guess users and try straight https://my.domain/~GuessedUser/whatever. And in the same time, seems impossible to use another per-user-dir elsewhere than in the AP_DOC_ROOT (suexec -V), which is '/var/www' for classical centos 7 package installation.

Comment: After solving issues with SELinux, I had the exact same error when trying to run a "hello world" shell script (that turned out to be group writeable). Upvoting both the detailed question and the step-by-step diagnostic approach in the answer.

Comment: Many thanks ! i have found different error but at least i have clue what to search for `cannot get docroot information` while the error log simply say `End of script output before headers` and i had no idea where to start ...

Answer (score 3):

For me, it worked when I changed the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/sh`) to `#!/usr/bin/env sh`. I found that any shebang lines from [What is the preferred Bash shebang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/preferred-bash-shebang) seemed to work (however note that `sh` is different from `bash` so if you want to use `sh` stick with it).

So this code worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
echo "Hello"
```

Also, according to the post mentioned above, it seems `/usr/bin/env sh` seems preferred over `/bin/sh`. I have no idea about the per directory stuff.

Comment: I had the same issue on OpenSUSE. "/usr/local/bin/perl" didn't work, but "/usr/bin/env perl" does work.

Answer (score 2):

This sometimes comes up when you try to call other Python module methods from your cgi where you might have left some 'print' statements (perhaps for debugging). So scan your code for any 'print' statement, sometimes this fixes the problem easily.

Comment: Thanks, nice tip, but as I said that is not my case, as it doesn't work even with a very simple bash script. I'm not even going that far as using complex python modules.

Answer (score 2):

Let only the file *owner* have write permissions on the cgi script, but not the *group*, that is `-rwxr-xr-x` and not `-rwxrwxr-x`.

In user directories often the group will be a personal user group that only the user is member of anyway, but it seems like Apache gets nervous about seing the *g+w* bit but gives a somewhat bogus error message about this.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to comment, but tried also this, `chmod 755 test.cgi`, without success.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same  issue. I **also** needed this:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```

which I found out by looking at the log (journalctl -b )
which told me...

SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/python2.7 from search access on the directory public_html.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the message "End of script output before headers: myscript.py" for a Python 2.x CGI script that ran fine from the command line.

The problem turned out to be that it wasn't executing correctly by the web server, even though it was from the command-line. Whatever error message the system gave back to the server, it surely didn't pass for CGI headers (e.g., "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"). Hence, this failure message.

For me, correcting it meant changing the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

To a more system-specific (but verifiable):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

Perhaps you're encountering something similar.

(FreeBSD 9.x.)

Comment: Thanks, I agree that it may be something similar, but I really can't understand what it may be... To avoid problems with the shebang, I also created a small C program that prints the header and a message, but the error is the same.

Comment: Can you have the program (or script) create a file somewhere to see if it's executing at all? I'm guessing it isn't.

Comment: Yep, you're right! It seems that it dies before it is even executed. Both bash and C program have this issue. Files are +x and I tried with 777 permissions, but still nothing.

Comment: Interesting! Closer! Maybe something on the way to the file itself: a parent directory or symbolic link permission, or points somewhere other than where you think it does.

Comment: All the directories from `/` up to `/home/myuser/public_html/cgi-bin` have write and execution privileges for all users, so I guess that apache should be able to access and execute the script... :\ What can it be?

Comment: Err sorry, I wrote "write and execution" but was "read and execution".

Comment: My next guess that it's going to the wrong place, missing your script entirely. Try putting it in /tmp and enabling cgi there (temporarily!). Enable directory indexes to see better through apache's eyes. Also try "apachectl -V" and look at SUEXEC_BIN.

Comment: I tried enabling directory indexes in cgi-bin (with `Options indexes`), but I can't make it work; both /var/www/cgi-bin (where cgi works) and per-user cgi-bin. I still have to test cgi in /tmp and using -V

Comment: `SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"` but I don't understand what to do with this info :D (I had to use `httpd -V` on Fedora 23). I tried to disable all the `ScriptAlias`es and all the automatic execution of CGIs (removed `ExecCGI` and Set/AddHandlers). If I list the cgi-bin directory, the list is there. If I add the handler and enable `ExecCGI`, the error is still there. I am currently trying to enable `ScriptLog`, but doesn't work, even if the log file is created and writable by apache-user.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your script as the apache user.

There are a number of reasons this could be happening.  @JimB mentions problem with the shebang.  @premganz mentions problems with debug print statements that fire before your Content-Type string is written. In my case it was a db connection failure.  It could be any other problem.

I found the best way to debug this is to run the script directly as the apache user on the command line, and see what errors it gives.

How to run your script as the Apache user

Assuming you're running apache2, and the apache user is www-data, and your cgi script is /myapp/myreport.py - you can do the following.

1. Allow logins as the www-data user, by changing its default shell. Edit /etc/passwd (temporarily)

   ```
   sudo su - 
   cd /etc
   cp -p passwd passwd.2017-10-22

   emacs passwd     # edit file - use your favorite editor
   ```

   Change:

   ```
   www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
   ```

   To:

   ```
   www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/bash
   ```
2. Log in as the www-data user

   ```
   sudo su - www-data
   ```
3. Set any environment vars.  Convert your apache SetEnv statements to export statements.  In my case, my apache config directory settings has these vars set

   ```
   SetEnv PYTHONPATH /myapp/lib
   SetEnv VCONF /myapp/conf/prod.yaml
   ```

   Run them as

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=/myapp/lib
   export VCONF=/myapp/conf/prod.yaml
   ```
4. Then try your cgi script

   ```
   cd /myapp
   ./myreport.py
   ```
5. You should see whatever error Apache is experiencing.  FIX THEM.
6. Set the www-data user's default shell back to /usr/sbin/nologin

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when we use print in older way.

```
print 'your test'
```

It should be for later version of Python.

```
print ('your test')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem executing a python cgi in a userdir.

/var/log/httpd/error_log reveals:

> [Fri Apr 26 13:09:41.840285 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 25421] [client 98.234.206.134:60837] End of script output before headers: index.cgi

The user being invoked in the URL was doug, user 42, group 42

I vaguely remembered suexec having a problem executing cgi scripts for a group or user below 1000.

So I created a new group called user1k as 1000.
Then I did

```
adduser -g 1000 -u 1000 dwg
chmod 755 /home/dwg
mkdir /home/dwg/public_html
```

And I placed my python cgi script into this directory.

Now that the group and user were >= 1000 the script began executing correctly.
I am not sure whether it was the user or the group which fixed the problem, but changing them both definitely solved it.

Note: It was the userid being below 1000 that was the problem.
So make the the userID of a userdir cgi executee is > 999.

Here is an excerpt from the `man suexec` output.

> Is the target userid ABOVE the minimum ID number? The minimum user ID
>   number is specified during configuration. This allows you to set the
>   lowest possible userid that will be allowed to execute CGI/SSI
>   programs. This is useful to block out "system" accounts.
>
> Is the target groupid ABOVE the minimum ID number? The minimum group
>   ID number is specified during configuration. This allows you to set
>   the lowest possible groupid that will be allowed to execute CGI/SSI
>   programs. This is useful to block out "system" groups.